# Aptana auto format

Tags: php, formatting, aptana

I'm trying out Aptana (standalone version) for PHP editing. Like its parent Eclipse, it has a lot of settings for code formatting. Unlike Eclipse, it doesn't seem to have an option for actually doing code formatting automatically or even by manual trigger. Is there a nonobvious option for this that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm also interested in knowing how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click > Format

Works fine for me. Make sure you have the PHP plugin installed if it isn't working for you

Comment: It throw error "com.aptana.formatter.epl/debug Error while formatting the code in your editor."

Answer (score 15):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is also the default keyboard shortcut for this.

Answer (score 0):

Install Aptana PHP, info available here:
https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/605-php-formatting